# Installing windows 8 on two machines with one disk (but two key codes)

Tags: windows-installation

I have Windows 8 on 2 computers but both need it reinstalled. The problem is that I can only find one of my disks but I have the key codes for each computer. Can I use the same disc on each using the 2 different key codes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As part of the installation process it will prompt you for the product key.  Just enter the key for each computer.  If you happen to have also misplaced your installation media (which I know you said you didn't) then you can also download that from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898.aspx#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=481&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0).  Again, using your own product keys.

Comment: Don't those download links require an MSDN subscription?

Comment: Darn it, you're probably right.  Edit: yes, you are right.

Comment: Here is the official answer for people without MSDN:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/windows-8-iso/ef5c3a70-1481-473f-8016-07475f150720

Comment: That second method only works for upgrade installs, not clean installs

Comment: Yeah it's pretty crappy for Microsoft.  They should allow ISO downloads - there's no reason to lock them behind MSDN.  Sorry for not realizing that sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming your installation disk is just a Windows 8 installation disk and not an OEM system recovery disk, just enter the appropriate product key when asked during each installation.

If you have an OEM system recovery disk, you may run into trouble with hardware compatibility if the two systems have different hardware because OEM disks normally have specific drivers built in. The product key may also be built into the disk, along with the bloatware/trialware that usually comes with a pre-installed Windows installation. In some cases, the disk may also format the entire drive in order to install a recovery partition as well. In short, OEM disks will do a lot more than simply reinstall the OS from scratch.